# how use npm packages with Vue SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-loader

i have created Vuejs app using vue-loader,now i need to use an installed npm package as follow :

```js
   var x = require('package-name')
   Vue.use(x)
```

but i have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: plugin.apply is not a function
```

dose Vuejs require a special type packages or it can work with any JavaScript package and this error can be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) are specific `Vue` packages that add global-level functionality to `Vue`, so if you aren't using a `Vue` plugin then you don't need to register it with `Vue` using `Vue.use()`.

In general there isn't any issue using non-vue-specific packages via `npm` but if you need to register something globally, you can usually get away with simply attaching it to `window` like so:

```
window.x = require('package-name');
```

Comment: You shouldn't attach to window because it breaks server rendering. Better options detailed here https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

Comment: @smiller171 thanks for sharing link. I have added the detail as answer , in case link doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

There are many approaches.

I am adding with respect @smiller comment and thanks for sharing the link . I am adding information here in case the link someday not work .

Credit to this link :- https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

**First approach** of-course @crig_h

```
window.x = require('package-name')
```

There are certain drawback . **don’t work with server rendering** . Otherwise everything will work fine in browser as `window` is global to browser , any properties attract to it will be accessible to whole app.

**The second approach is** .

Use Import with the js portion in the `.vue` file , Like this.

if inside the '.vue' file.

```
<script>
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  created() {
   console.log(_.isEmpty() ? 'Lodash is available here!' : 'Uh oh..');
  }
} 
</script>
```

If you have seperate file for `.js` then same like this there will we no `<script>` tag.

**And Third method**

where ever in the project you import `vue`. You can write this statement 
`import Vue from "vue";`

```
import moment from 'moment';
Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

This will set the relevant properties to to `Vue` . And you can use it any where like this . As  Vue is global scope of app.

```
export default {
  created() {
    console.log('The time is ' . this.$moment().format("HH:mm"));
  }
}
```

**ADDED FOR CSS**

you can do import in src/main.js file in vue.js project .

import './animate.css'

Also if you like to import in template .

Inside the template you can do this.

`<style src="./animate.css"></style>`

Also have a look on `css-loader` package . what it does ?

Comment: what if my package is animate.css, would I still write `import animate from 'animate.css'`?

Comment: @AkinHwan I have added css import method in answer too.

Comment: Hi, there is a typo in your answer. Object.definePrototype => Object.defineProperty. Have a great day.

Comment: You should probably also add the alternative syntax: Vue.prototype.$something = importedSomething

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of these answers worked for me what i ended up doing is

```js
export default {
  computed() {
    x () {
      return require('package-name')
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it as `x.functionName()` or whatever

Answer (score 1):

There is better solution ... First import your package in main.js

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "package-name";
```

After that's you code inside mounted method as javascript

```js
<script>
export default {
   mounted() {
      const any = require("package-name");
      // your code as normal js
   },
};
</script>
```